# bidimensional array with list comprehension - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a bidimensional array using list comprehension.

```
a = [[0 for y in range(1, 10)] for x in range(1, 10)]
```

This should create a 9x9 'matrix' whose first item is a[1][1], and last is a[9][9]

However this is not happening, and when I try to print the last element:

```
print(a[9][9])
```

I get an out of range error.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You do have a 9x9 *matrix* (or list of lists), but since indices are zero based, you can only index from 0 to 8 along both axes.

The start value `1` in the `range` function does not influence the start value of your indexing; it will always be zero.